# Simple promise with Angular's $http

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I find myself doing things like this a lot in my Angular services:

```
getStats: function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('/stats').success(function(stats) {
    deferred.resolve(stats);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Note that the promise I'm returning resolves to the returned data. It's not a situation where I can use a `.success` callback.

Is there a simpler way to do this without using `$q`?

Answer (score 2):

That should work, because `$http.get` returns promise object,

```
getStats: function() {
       return $http.get('/stats');
    }
```

in your code you use it like this:

```
someService.getStats().success(successFN);
```

Comment: It's not a situation where I want to use a success callback. I specifically want the returned promise to resolve to the retrieved data.

Answer (score 0):

Create an API service:

```
app.factory('apiService', ['$http', function($http) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        getStats: function (deviceId) {
            return $http.get('/stats');
        }
    }
}
```

Then inject the apiCall in your controller and use the `getStats` method.

```
app.controller("MyController", ['$scope', 'apiService', '$routeParams', function($scope, apiService, $routeParams) {
    'use strict';
    angular.extend($scope, {
        info: {},
        deviceId: $routeParams.deviceId,
        loadInfo: function () {
            apiService
                .getStats($scope.deviceId)
                .succes(function (res, statusCode) {
                    $scope.info = res;
                })
                .error(function () {
                    alert('Oh NOS!');
                })
        }
    });

    $scope.loadInfo();
}]);
```

Comment: It's not a situation where I want to use a success callback. I specifically want the returned promise to resolve to the retrieved data.